# Scanning algorithm to find intersections between lines

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, pseudocode

I have a set of lines L and a set of points P. I want to find how many lines of L intersect by a horizontal line passing through a point p. How can i compute this?

Comment: Are you expecting to do this without looking at every line in L (say, by using some optimises container datatype)?

Comment: Do you have a set of *lines* or a set of *line segments*? In the former case it's simply checking which lines are parallel to the X axis.

Comment: Also how are your lines `L` stored, assuming they're line segments? As  pairs of points (start/end)?

Comment: What if a line segment is intersected by multiple horizontal lines originating from points in P? Does that count multiple times or only once?

Comment: Lines or line segments ?? How many lines ? How many points ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your set of line segments are stored as `(start, stop)` pairs and multiple intersections count multiple times, this answer applies.

The first step is to throw away all `x` coordinates - only the `y` coordinates matter. Then construct an array of pairs from L and P. For each line segment in L add `(y_start, START)` and `(y_stop, STOP)` to the array. For each point in P add `(y, POINT)` to the array (`START, STOP, POINT` are just arbitrary values, e.g. an C enum). Sort the array of pairs by the first value.

Then, initialize `n = 0, l = 0` and loop through the array and look at the second value of each pair:

1. If it is `START`, increment `l`.
2. If it is `STOP`, decrement `l`.
3. If it is `POINT`, add `l` to `n`.

`n` is your final result. Total complexity is dominated by the sort, `O((|L| + |P|) log(|L| + |P|))`.